# UICollectionView: add spacing between header and items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to add some spacing between my header and the actual items, which currently look like this:

[image: screenshot1]

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    // Create header
    switch kind{
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = iconCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "customIconHeaderView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustonIconHeaderView
            headerView.setUp() //add whatever into the view
            return headerView
        default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }

}
```

Comment: you could add a spacer cell as the first cell in the section. not an ideal implementation I know, but fool proof

Answer (score 39):

You are basically talking about adding a top margin to the collection view section, for that you would set *top inset* for the section. To do it in code, implement `insetForSectionAtIndex`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)
}
```

If you don't want to implement the `insetForSectionAtIndex`, you could also do something like this in an appropriate method e.g. `viewDidLoad`:

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)
```

In Interface Builder, Select collection view and change the value for *Section Insets -> Top* as shown in the image below:

[image]

**NOTE**: This only works if you are using Flow Layout.

Comment: I'm doing everything in code, when i change `insetForSectionAtIndex`, it increases the top margin for the header as well. So everything moves down.

Comment: are you saying you don't want to implement the `insetForSectionAtIndex` method? if so, yes you could do this too:

`let layout = collection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout;
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0);`

Comment: no, I implemented `insetForSectionAtIndex`, which is currently `UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 20.0)`, but when i change `top` to say `10`, not only the items move down, the header also moves down. but what i want is just spacing between the section header and the items.

Comment: strange, how have you returned your section header? you are returning it from your `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView` right? I just tried it, it works for me.

Comment: Never mind, it was because I was also using a custom flow layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do is to increase your header container's heigh using

`collectionView(_:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:)`

Example:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 0, height: yourHeaderContentHeight + yourHeaderMarginToCell)
}
```

**Edit:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "YourID", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let yourCustomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourHeaderWidth, height: yourHeaderHeight))

    headerView.addSubview(yourCustomView)

    return headerView
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: yourHeaderWidth, height: yourHeaderHeight + yourHeaderMargin)
}
```

Comment: that just increased the height of the header, i'm using a custom view for the header though, i don't know if that affects anything

Comment: For example, your custom header view is `40` pt height and the `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` is `60` which will provide  `20` pt gap on the bottom if you set your custom header view's `frame` properly :)

Comment: how do i set the custom view's height, I'm doing everything in code. Do i do it in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`?

Comment: oh so you're suggesting using `headerView` as a container view? The way I'm doing it is I customized a `UIView` to be the `headerView`, so I just need to dequeue it and return it in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`.

Comment: Correct :) but if you don't want to have your customView inside the headerView, you can always draw your view and make a white(any color) bar on the bottom to simulate same visual effect

Comment: This seems like the easiest way to add space between the header and the items. If you build your collection view and header in IB, this is easy to do by setting all of your constraints to the top of the header view and making sure they don't move as you change its size